# bump in the siding

Tags: exterior, siding

There is a bump in the siding of our building. I would like to know what could cause that and how to fix it.

I don't know if it is only something esthetic or more serious.[image]

The siding is a made of wood fider. The brand is Canexel I think or something similar.

This is in Canada and it is the south side of the building.

Comment: Is the bump new or has it always been there?  Where is the bump, is it middle of wall or where two houses meet?

Comment: It seems the bump is caused by expansion under extreme heat. Did your local have experienced heatwave recently? If the board is free to push down, then there is nothing wrong from inside. You may need to reinstall the siding and leave larger gaps to obsorb the expansion.

Comment: The vent below it, is it an intake or exhaust? Might there be condensation coming out? More appropriately, steam or water vapor at the least...

Comment: The separation between condo is between the vent. They are both exhaust I think for the dryer and air exchanger.